# Due to a recent security incident, all user tokens have been invalidated

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

So I uninstalled the newer version of node that I had on my machine(`v8.11.3`) and then installed the earlier version `v6.11.0` (*because my project needs earlier version to do a grunt build*). Now when I try to do **`npm install`** to restore the packages for my project it gives the following error.

> Due to a recent security incident, all user tokens have been invalidated. Please see https://status.npmjs.org/incidents/dn7c1fgrr7ng for more details. To generate a new token, visit https://www.npmjs.com/settings/~/tokens or run `npm login`.

I tried doing a `npm login` to generate the token (*token generation was successful*) but throws same error when I try doing `npm install` the next time.

Comment: Thank you everyone for trying to help out, found out my npmrc file was incorrectly configured. I had to add some lines for my project there.

Answer (score 1):

I got same issue last time.

Steps that I did:

1. I went to https://www.npmjs.com/settings/~/tokens and generate my token there.
2. Open new terminal
3. Execute `npm whoami` and check if your username appears. If not, do `npm login`
4. You should be able to `npm install` again

Hope it helps

Comment: Ok I followed your steps, did **npm whoami** and saw my username there, then I tried doing the **npm install** but the same problem is there.

Comment: @RomanRajBajracharya You could have solved the token issue and having another error. Npm just displays that warning and it can be mistaken for the error message...

Comment: @RomanRajBajracharya interesting, maybe need to wait some time for npm to sync the token into our local computer.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem as you.

If you save the npm token **inside** your project folder, delete the file and do `npm install`. Look for the file named `.npmrc` and delete that.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Ok I found out my .npmrc file was not correctly configured. I had to make some changes in the urls I had there. Thanks for the guidance. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to install a package and I was getting the same error. After some time i realised that the package name which I was installing doesn't exists and npm was giving me this error.